# Deprecations in project after upgrade to Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, deprecated, symfony-3.3

I have just upgrade my Symfony project to the latest version (3.3). Now my project does give some deprecations warnings but does not point anything to my code.

In total of 8 warning I need to fix before I can upgrade to a newer version later.
[image]

I checked my composer.json file for out dated releases but couldn't find any.
Composer.json file that is in my project looks like:

```
{
    "name": "domji/collection-manager",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["app/AppKernel.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/",
            "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.*",
        "symfony/console": "3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "ornicar/gravatar-bundle" : "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
        "imdbphp/imdbphp": "^5.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me where the decrecated calls come from?

Comment: create a [fresh  test install for the recent version](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) and check the frontend controllers (e.g. `web/app_dev.php`, `web/app.php`). And I think some errors are related to your config files in `app/config`as well.

Comment: You was correct. My app.php and app_dev.php are not updated and some configs are not correct. Now only 1 warning I have. But this one I think its because of some bundles that I'm use: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension::addClassesToCompile() is deprecated since version 3.3, to be removed in 4.0.
Hide trace
{▼
  E:\Projecten\cm\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension.php:62: {▶}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the newest version of Assetic bundle fixed all my deprecation errors.